# References ok but no bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I would like to create a bibliography which includes two separate sections. While the references appear correctly in the text, the bibliography is empty. There are no warnings but the biber log states:

```
INFO - Sorting list 'apa/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'apa' and locale 'en-GB'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-GB'
```

This seems to relate to my problem. How can I solve it?

The following mwe replicates my problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\bibname.bib}
@book{B1,
  author =       {Name1, Surname1},
  title =        {Title of the first book in the First category},
  publisher =    {Name of the Publisher},
  year =         {2017},
  keywords =     {firstcategory}
}
@book{B2,
  author =       {Name2, Surname2},
  title =        {Title of the second book in the First category},
  publisher =    {Name of the Publisher},
  year =         {2016},
  keywords =     {firstcategory}
}
@article{A1,
  author =       {Name3, Surname3},
  title =        {This is the title of first article in the Second category},
  journal =      {Name of the Journal},
  year =         {2017},
  volume =       {01},
  number =       {12},
  pages =        {1-20},
  keywords =     {secondcategory}
}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{one}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{two}
\addtocategory{one}{firstcategory}
\addtocategory{two}{secondcategory}
\addbibresource{\bibname.bib}
\begin{document}
I would like to split my bibliography in two section. Authors \parencite{B1,B2} with the keyword "firstcategory" in the bib. file should appear in the First Category and author \parencite{A1} with the keyword "secondcategory" should appear in the Second Category.
\printbibliography[category=one,category=two]
\end{document}
```

I alreday tried `sorting=anyt` and `\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]` but it did not work.

Comment: The `british` option of babel should be set as an option  to `\documentclass`. Try adding `\nocite{*}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the bibliography by categories, you have to add to categories the `bibtex keys`, not the `keywords` (but alternatively, you can filter the `\printbibliography` command by keywords). To print all categories, use the `\bibbycategory` command. To print some, you can of course use `\printbibliography[category=…]`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@book{B1,
  author = {Name1, Surname1},
  title = {Title of the first book in the First category},
  publisher = {Name of the Publisher},
  year = {2017},
  keywords = {firstcategory}
}
@book{B2,
  author = {Name2, Surname2},
  title = {Title of the second book in the First category},
  publisher = {Name of the Publisher},
  year = {2016},
  keywords = {firstcategory}
}
@article{A1,
  author = {Name3, Surname3},
  title = {This is the title of first article in the Second category},
  journal = {Name of the Journal},
  year = {2017},
  volume = {01},
  number = {12},
  pages = {1-20},
  keywords = {secondcategory}
}
\end{filecontents}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{one}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{two}
\addtocategory{one}{B1,B2}
\addtocategory{two}{A1}
\defbibheading{one}{\section*{First category}}
\defbibheading{two}{\section*{Second category}}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
I would like to split my bibliography in two section. Authors \parencite{B1,B2} with the keyword "firstcategory" in the bib. file should appear in the First Category and author \parencite{A1} with the keyword "secondcategory" should appear in the Second Category.

%\printbibliography[category=one]%
%\printbibliography[category=two]%

\bibbycategory

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your bibliography is empty because `\printbibliography[category=one,category=two]` will only print entries which are in both category "one" and "two" at the same time. I suggest to use a filter instead:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\bibname.bib}
@book{B1,
  author =       {Name1, Surname1},
  title =        {Title of the first book in the First category},
  publisher =    {Name of the Publisher},
  year =         {2017},
  keywords =     {firstcategory}
}
@book{B2,
  author =       {Name2, Surname2},
  title =        {Title of the second book in the First category},
  publisher =    {Name of the Publisher},
  year =         {2016},
  keywords =     {firstcategory}
}
@article{A1,
  author =       {Name3, Surname3},
  title =        {This is the title of first article in the Second category},
  journal =      {Name of the Journal},
  year =         {2017},
  volume =       {01},
  number =       {12},
  pages =        {1-20},
  keywords =     {secondcategory}
}
\end{filecontents}
\defbibfilter{myfilter}{%
    keyword=firstcategory or keyword=secondcategory
}

\addbibresource{\bibname.bib}
\begin{document}
I would like to split my bibliography in two section. Authors \cite{B1,B2} with the keyword "firstcategory" in the bib. file should appear in the First Category and author \cite{A1} with the keyword "secondcategory" should appear in the Second Category.

\printbibliography[filter=myfilter]


\end{document}
```

[image]

(If you need the categories, the same should be possible for them, but your example looked like keywords would be the more natural thing to use)